# palm webos device does not save images but emulator does

Tags: javascript, webos

I am trying to save image to media/internal/wallpapers. In the emulator, it is saving it, but when the same code I run on the device it does not save it:

```
path.exists('/media/internal/wallpapers/', function(exists){
   if (exists) {    
    fs.open('/media/internal/wallpapers/i.png', 'w', 666, function( e, id ) {
    fs.write(id, buff, null, buff.length, 0, function(){
      if(err)
        callback({
           error: false,
           reply: err
         });
        if(written){
                callback({
             error: false,
             reply: written
           });
        }  
          fs.close(id, function(){

          });
        });
      });


     }
     else {
       callback({
         error: true,
         reply: 'File did not exist.'
       });
     }
   });
```

Why is it doing so? Does the emulator contain bugs, or is it a limitation of the device?

Comment: Can you show us some code?  Most likely you are doing something that is allowed on the emulator but not on the device.

Comment: path.exists('/media/internal/wallpapers/', function(exists){
  if (exists) {  
  fs.open('/media/internal/wallpapers/i.png', 'w', 666, function( e, id ) {
  fs.write(id, buff, null, buff.length, 0, function(){
   if(err)
    callback({
      error: false,
      reply: err
     });
    if(written){
            callback({
       error: false,
       reply: written
      });
    } 
       fs.close(id, function(){
  
       });
     });
   });
      
     
   }
   else {
    callback({
     error: true,
     reply: 'File did not exist.'
    });
   }
  });

Comment: the above code is running on the emulator and saving file to wallpapers but is not running on the device...y ? and does not throw any error... i cant debug on the service side how to debug it ?

Comment: are you in usb (mass storage) mode perhaps?